# How would you dynamically hide or display a SSRS header based on a parameter?

Tags: reporting-services

I need to hide or display the header of a SSRS report based on the value of a parameter.  The parameter is called "Show Header?", and the values of this parameter are true and false.  Is there a hide property for headers?  If so, I'm not able to find it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are talking about the table Headers or the report header (some people seem to use the term interchangeably).

I'm still self learning SSRS so there may be better options out there but a quick test i found the following.

For a Boolean Parameter type:

I used the logic below to hide the visibility based on parameter (you may want to play around with the true/false order depending on your parameter to get it to work how you want):

```
=IIF(Parameters!ShowHeader.Value, False,True)
```

**Table Headers:**

Just highlight the text boxes you want to show/hide and open up the properties, under Visibility select "Show or Hide Based on Expression"

(NB. i found highlighting the full row would only let you select the full tablix properties not the single row so I just shift clicked all the cells and pasted the IIF statement into the "Hidden" Property for the selection in the properties window)
[image: Hidden Property Display]

**Report Headers:**

I am not sure you can hide the Header (couldn't see any immediate hiding properties or options), however you could hide the contents of the header using the same sort of process (right click properties and alter the Visibility setting or add the code into the Hidden property). In testing I found that the header would reduce to remove white space when items where hidden so may work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

The sneaky way I've found to get around the limitation of SSRS on this is to put my "header" in the first row of the first tablix and just hiding the actual report header, which you probably know cannot be deleted.  That way, I can show or hide the first row of the tablix by whatever criteria I desire. This method works well for me.